# ViewBag.Title not working in my code ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to Visual Studio and am having difficulty making the ViewBag.Title function correctly.

Here is my code the ViewBag.Title is not working properly and gettin printed on screen in incorrect position and as the full string "ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";"

```
  @model IEnumerable<Employees.Models.Employee>
  @{WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(Model);}
  {
  ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
  }
  @section featured {
       <section class="featured">
           <div class="content-wrapper">
               <hgroup class="title">
                  <h1>@ViewBag.Title.</h1>
                  <h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>
               </hgroup>
   @grid.GetHtml(columns: new[] {
   ....
   ....
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you just need to prefix that code block where you assign the `ViewBag.Title` with an `@`

```
@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
  }
```

This was rendering as is like it was straight HTML

Comment: You could move that code into one block

@{WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(Model); ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";}  It's good practice to do that as much as possible for precompiler optimizations.  When you publish the website you can opt to have it precompiled and it will build all of the views into generated assemblies to increase performance.  Keeping as much of the code as possible in one block optimizes the code generation when precompiled.  When not precompiled, the MVC engine compiles the views at runtime (when accessed) increasing load times.

Comment: @Ryios Yeah the website takes a few seconds to load. And its faster inside the block.

Answer (score -1):

To Use Title in SubViews(Partial Views) TempData

```html
 TempData["pagetitle"] = "Title";
```